# GWT CELLTABLE : How to set columns descending icon on celltable header?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

How to set columns descending icon i.e. DESC icon on celltable header  ?

On celltable loading.. I want to set sorting order to column i.e. previously sorted column/sorting order by user (In last login , before logout)

I tried following way
table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn); i.e setting column ascending to true with ASC Icon on top of header.It works fine

Now I want to set column in descending i.e DESC icon on top header ? How to do it ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call `table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn)` if no sort info is set on the column it sets the sort to ascending. If you call it another time it reverses the sort order.

```
// Show the descending sort icon on a column.
ColumnSortInfo sortInfo = table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn);
if (sortInfo.isAscending()) {
    table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn);
}
```

To set the sort icon according to state saved in variable sortOrder:

```
// Assuming sortedOrder = true means ascending
// and sortedOrder = false means descending
ColumnSortInfo sortInfo = table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn);
if (sortedOrder && !sortInfo.isAscending()) {
    table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn);
}
else if (!sortedOrder && sortInfo.isAscending()) {
    table.getColumnSortList().push(testColumn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. jonic above code is used for flipped the order. My problem is that I want to show sorted order of column after celltable loading. eg. I have xml. I am getting only one column information i.e column(columnname, sortedOrder[false/true],dataTypeOf) as per column information I want to set ASC/DESC icon close to Column as per value.